# Linux apache mod_auth_sspi installation

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, mod-auth

I am running an Apache/2.4.7 Linux webserver and working on an intranet project where users of Internet Explorer need to be authenticated automatically. Their windows username has to be displayed in a greeting on the intranet homepage.

I downloaded the [mod_auth_sspi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-auth-sspi/) module from SourceForge and unzipped the file.

I located a **mod_auth_sspi.so** file in **mod_auth_sspi-1.0.4\bin**.

I move that .so file into **/etc/apache2/mod-available** and added the following line to the bottom of my **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** file:

```
LoadModule mod_auth_sspi mods-available/mod_auth_sspi.so
```

With all that done I attempted to reload my server and got the following error:

```
sudo apache2ctl restart 
apache2: Syntax error on line 225 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Cannot load mods-available/mod_auth_sspi.so into server: /etc/apache2/mods-available/mod_auth_sspi.so: invalid ELF header
Action 'restart' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

I am very new into installing and configuring Apache module.

**Can anyone advice if my steps listed above are correct and what I can do to correctly get mod_auth_sspi working?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to install a Win32 Binary into Linux... it won't work (I'm acutally facing the same Problem). As far as I see, there is no source for Linux (as development has stopped) anymore... if you find something, let me know!

Answer (score -1):

In this link it shows how to set up in windows / linux

https://docs.moodle.org/25/en/NTLM_authentication

Comment: Links can die, and sites can change. Please provide answers that remain useful after links die, etc.